# Naturality of Lie derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

It was left to me as an exercise to show the naturality of the Lie derivative of arbitrary tensors on a smooth manifold. Is the following argument correct (it seems too easy)?

Let $X$ be a vector field and let $T$ be a tensor on a smooth manifold $N$. Let $\theta^p(t)$ be the flow associated to $X$ such that $\theta^p(0)=p$ and $\theta'^p(0)=X.$

Consider an arbitrary diffeomorphism $\phi$ from a smooth manifold $M$ to $N$, such that $\phi(x)=p.$ I need to show $\phi^*(L_XT)= L_{\phi^*X} \phi^*T.$

We compute $\phi^* (L_X T)$ at the point $x$ 
\begin{align} \phi^*(L_X T)&= \phi^* \left(\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} (\theta^p(t) T- T ) \right)\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} \left(\phi^* (\theta^p(t) T- T)\right) \\
&= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{t} (\phi^*(\theta^p(t)) T- \phi^*T))\\
&= L_{\phi^*X}\phi^*T.
\end{align}

The above computation uses only the fact that $\phi^*$ commutes with limits, which is clear from writing everything out in coordinates and using the fact that the maps are all smooth.

Comment: are you sure you used the standard notation?

Comment: Well... I think so. What symbols are confusing you?